# How to emulate a modal dialog in WTL?

Tags: visual-c++, wtl

Modal dialogs are nice and easy to use. Problem is that they don't allow me to handle the message loop myself. So I thought I could perhaps use a modeless dialog to emulate a modal one and still be in charge of the message loop myself in order to handle accelerators.

#### Goal

What I want to achieve in general is the ability to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>) while *the dialog* has the focus and then I want to be able to react to that by copying some information into the clipboard. So if anyone knows a way to do that with modal dialogs in WTL, that also would answer my question.

#### What I am doing right now

Now what I currently do is deriving my dialog class from `CDialogImpl<T>` and `CMessageFilter` in order to put me in charge of `PreTranslateMessage`. In there I simply use `CAccelerator::TranslateAccelerator` and `CWindow::IsDialogMessage` to process accelerators and dialog box messages.

In `OnInitDialog` I populate the accelerator table and add the message filter to the ("global") message loop. The accelerator table has the same resource ID as the dialog itself:

```
m_accel.Attach(AtlLoadAccelerators(IDD));
CMessageLoop* pLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
pLoop->AddMessageFilter(this);
```

Then I created a surrogate for `DoModal` by the name `PretendModal` which uses the "global" message loop.

Now the effect (other than the dialog appearing on the task bar) that I am seeing is that the application, once the modal dialog gets closed, cannot be closed anymore. To be precise, the main message loop receives `WM_QUIT` (the `ATLTRACE2` in WTL::CMessageLoop::Run() gives that away, but it still hangs after this stunt (main frame window gets closed, WM_QUIT gets posted, but the process does not exit). The whole thing behaves the same if I use a separate `CMessageLoop` inside `PretendModal` (instead of the "global" one).

Even moving another separate new instance of `CMessageLoop` into its own thread (after all message loops are thread-local) does not seem to resolve this issue. This leaves me puzzled as to what exactly I am doing wrong here.

NB: The handler for `IDCANCEL` and `IDOK` removes the dialog class (i.e. the message filter) from the message loop.

#### Question

What am I doing wrong in my attempt to emulate a modal dialog using a modeless one? Alternatively, how can I catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>) when using a modal dialog derived just from `CDialogImpl<T>`.

---

#### The class

```
class CAboutDlg :
    public CDialogImpl<CAboutDlg>,
    public CMessageFilter
{
    CAccelerator m_accel;
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUT };

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CAboutDlg)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDOK, OnCloseCmd)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDCANCEL, OnCloseCmd)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
    {
        if (!m_accel.IsNull() && m_accel.TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd, pMsg))
            return TRUE;
        return CWindow::IsDialogMessage(pMsg);
    }

    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&)
    {
        m_accel.Attach(AtlLoadAccelerators(IDD));
        if (m_bModal)
        {
            CMessageLoop* pLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
            pLoop->AddMessageFilter(this);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    void PretendModal(HWND hwndParent = ::GetActiveWindow())
    {
        CMessageLoop* pLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
        if (pLoop && ::IsWindow(hwndParent))
        {
            HWND dlg = Create(*this);
            if (::IsWindow(dlg))
            {
                ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
                pLoop->Run();
            }
        }
    }

    LRESULT OnCloseCmd(WORD, WORD, HWND, BOOL&)
    {
        if (m_bModal)
            EndDialog(0);
        else
        {
            CMessageLoop* pLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
            pLoop->RemoveMessageFilter(this);
            ::DestroyWindow(*this);
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's hard to believe the whole message loop has to be replaced just to capture a keypress! Needed something similar because I was looking for way to catch the Escape key. Apparently the ATL/WTL modal boxes don't close by default when ESC is pressed. Before this method I tried to use `SetWindowsHook`, which worked but is considered even worse. I still wonder if there isn't a more elegant way to connect a message filter to the "standard" `DoModal` message loop...

Comment: @E.vanPutten: If there is, it has eluded me. But I don't think the solution is all too bad. It seems to be playing by the rules without diverging too much from the expected behavior for modal dialogs.

Comment: You are right, it is not too bad. But it is still a lot of work for just catching a few keystrokes. Playing by the rules (more) is also why I tried to stay away from that windows (message) hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So meanwhile I managed to achieve what I wanted. This seems to be working nicely and I haven't found any negative side effects as of yet.

In order to do what I want, I introduced an `EmulateModal()` function which kind of mimics the `DoModal()` function of `DialogImpl`.

That function looks as follows:

```
void EmulateModal(_In_ HWND hWndParent = ::GetActiveWindow(), _In_ LPARAM dwInitParam = NULL)
{
    ATLASSERT(!m_bModal);
    ::EnableWindow(hWndParent, FALSE);
    Create(hWndParent, dwInitParam);
    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    m_loop.AddMessageFilter(this);
    m_loop.Run();
    ::EnableWindow(hWndParent, TRUE);
    ::SetForegroundWindow(hWndParent);
    DestroyWindow();
}
```

The `m_loop` member is a `CMessageLoop` owned by the `CDialogImpl`-derived class (which also inherits from `CMessageFilter` as shown in the question).

The only other special handling that is needed, was to add the following code to the command ID handler which watches for `IDOK` and `IDCANCEL` (which in my case are both meant to close the dialog), i.e. inside `OnCloseCmd`.

```
if(m_bModal)
{
    EndDialog(wID);
}
else
{
    m_loop.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    PostMessage(WM_QUIT);
}
```

It is important to remove the message filter (i.e. `PreTranslateMessage`) from the message loop *prior* to calling `DestroyWindow()`. It is also **very important** to exit the "inner" message loop which is owned by the `CDialogImpl`-derived class and whose `Run()` is being called from `EmulateModal()` above.

So the gist is this:

1. get rid of the `PretendModal()` method from my question
2. make use of an "inner" message loop instead of using the top-level one

Comment: There's an ever so subtle bug lingering in this code. I believe you can make it surface by temporarily switching to another application, after launching the modal dialog. If you now dismiss the dialog, the system moves the wrong window to the foreground. The core issue is, that the code enables the owner window too late (after destroying the dialog). For a more comprehensive explanation see [The correct order for disabling and enabling windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040227-00/?p=40463/).

Comment: @IInspectable: thanks for pointing it out. I'll have a look at it and adjust my code accordingly. I think I understand the nature of the problem and what needs to be done.

Comment: @IInspectable: turns out in my own code I already was calling `::SetForegroundWindow` after enabling the parent window in `EmulateModal`. That should do the trick, right? Or would that be prone to said flicker and I should therefore move the enabling and setting to foreground to _before_ the `DestroyWindow`?

Comment: Calling [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) may fail when called after the system has activated another window, causing the taskbar button to flash. The restrictions placed on that API call aren't entirely clear to me, and the misleading documentation doesn't help much in sorting it all out. If I were to implement this, I'd probably play it safe, and activate the owner before destroying the modal UI.

Comment: @IInspectable: "activate" as in `EnableWindow()` or "activate" as in `ShowWindow()`.

Comment: *"Activate"* in the final sentence was the wrong term. I meant to write *"**enable** the owner before destroying the modal UI"*. That's enough for the window manager to activate the owner once the modal UI is destroyed.